# Nsdictionary as a data type

Tags: ios, nsdictionary

Would nsdictionary be a good data type to use for storing long string values as values and names of those descriptions for keys? Or would a different data type be more effective? I am using it for animals, and having and array hold all the data then using a dictionary to point to the name and description of the animal. I'm just curious if this is used for smaller data like states and capitals

Or should I just use a `#Define @"rhino description"`

```
[Animal animalObj:@"rhino" location:@"the water" description:[[self setGenericAnimals] valueForKey:@"Rhino"]]
```

Answer (score 1):

NSDictionary is OK for this. Whats great about using NSDictionary is you can save your data as JSON in a sperate file and then serialzie it into a NSDictonary when you need it. This would make it easier for you to manage all your data and it seperates it from your application.

this is a good start on how to convert JSON into a NSdictionary.
http://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/working-with-json-in-ios-5

Remember though that the entire NSDictionary must fit into memory so if your going to have thousands of strings you might want to separate that into different JSON files and then serialize them into Dictionaries when you need them.

Another thing to remember is that if you want to do simple comparisons and sorting options on objects you are better using CoreData as this allows you to store lots of strings and easily access them.